# Where is the value for Wordpress bloginfo('stylesheet_url') saved?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, url, stylesheet

I'm setting up a Wordpress site (as a newbie). The way it works is that I have an installation on a development server where I change stuff and then someone else moves my changes to the live server.

Now I've come across the problem that while everything works fine on the dev server, the live server doesn't pull the correct CSS stylesheets. In the `<head>` of the HTML file I can see two links to the stylesheet, and both point to the **development server URL** rather than the **live server URL**.

If I'm not mistaken, this info is pulled from `bloginfo('stylesheet_url')`.

Now I have no clue where the value for this comes from. I've searched every single file in the live installation and could *not* find any hardcoded links (apart from that I'd have remembered to have set up hardcoded links).

Where then is this value saved?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're going to move databases from local to live - or from any domain to another - you need to change URLs in the database. Also see [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

You can use these queries in phpmyadmin to change URLs:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://olddomain.com','http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
```

**A better method (answer updated 8/01/2014)** is to use https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ , which correctly deals with serialized data in the database; the SQL queries abov will break serialied data, and you may lose some theme and ohter options as a result. That script is recommened on the http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress Codex page.

Comment: Thanks all for your quick answers. I'll choose this as preferred answer as it is the most comprehensive, provides actual SQL code and gives a link to the respective Codex site.

Answer (score 3):

Well its not saved, the stylesheet_url is you current themes url.
     `wp-content/themes/your-theme/` . 
You current theme's folder name is stored in the database's options table usually `wp_options`. Where `template='your-theme-name'`. If you want to change the site url change `siteurl` row's value in the same table

Comment: Thanks, I've used your answer as take-off point even before the other answers came in and changed the table accordingly: `update wp_options 
set option_value = 'http://...live URL...' 
where option_name = 'siteurl';`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably with the base URL, and not specific to the CSS. Look under the admin panel, Settings -> General -> "WordPress address (URL)" and "Site address (URL)"