# How to change value stylesheet_url in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, url, stylesheet

I'm trying to modify a theme in wordpress and one thing I've stumbled upon is the way this theme is including a stylesheet file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
```

As I discovered stylesheet_url refers to the file named style.css in the root folder. How can I change the value of the stylesheet_url so that my stylesheet file in the css/ directory will be loaded instead of the default one?

Comment: Doesn't that seem like an awful lot of work to go through when you can just swap the style rules between files?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can put new css file path like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/newstyle.css" />
```

and you can remove default css path if you don't need.
hope this helps you. All the best ;)

Comment: If you want to add this to the wordpress styles then you need to add this to with wp_enqueue_style and use get_bloginfo('template_directory'). This should be done in the functions.php file.

Answer (score 1):

In function `blog_info()`.

Here is the [link to do this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) and also check [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) and [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_uri).

You can also see an example here: [Where is the value for Wordpress bloginfo('stylesheet_url') saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190623/where-is-the-value-for-wordpress-bloginfostylesheet-url-saved).

Comment: Thanx. the articles were very helpful