# Wordpress bloginfo('stylesheet_url'), where is this coming from?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, stylesheet

I'm trying to make some modifications to a wordpress theme that I purchased, and I'm having some problems editing the CSS. I've made tweaks to `style.css` in the theme's directory, but when I test my site, some (not all) of the CSS changes I've made are being overwritten by code that is being inserted into my index file when the page loads. If I view page source, I can see that css styling is being added directly after `<style type="text/css" media="screen">`

I sifted through the php files and found that in `header.php` there is a line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

I believe this is the source of the phantom CSS code that is overriding the changes that I made in `style.css`, but I don't know how to access/modify/delete the css formatting that I believe is coming from `stylesheet_url`

Anybody have any ideas? I found these stackoverflow links that seem to be related, but don't solve my issue:

1) [How to change value stylesheet_url in wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448779/how-to-change-value-stylesheet-url-in-wordpress)

2) [Where is the value for Wordpress bloginfo('stylesheet_url') saved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190623/where-is-the-value-for-wordpress-bloginfostylesheet-url-saved)

Comment: Have you tried putting your CSS edits at the bottom of the `style.css` you were editing? It may be getting overridden by code that's later in the file. You may also want to view the stylesheet that you believe to be problematic using Chrome's developer tools to see if it gives you any indication of where it's coming from.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `blog_info('stylesheet_url')` [**is exactly the same**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/general-template.php#L483) as calling `get_stylesheet_uri()`, which in turn returns the address of the current theme **`style.css`** file.

So, that's not a *phantom URL*, it's actually the file you're working with. As pointed by nicolekanderson in comments, you should put your CSS overrides at the end of the file.

Further suggestions:

- inspect the HTML output to make sure no other stylesheet is being loaded (maybe the theme also uses [`wp_enqueue_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) - check for that in `functions.php`).
- don't modify the theme and use a [Child Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) instead, it's quite easy to do and you can have your modifications clearly separated from the original theme.
- use [Jetpack](http://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack), it has a module to add Extra CSS that works quite well, just add the rules in the Dashboard, update and it's live on the site.